# sql/mysql search one field for two keywords

Tags: mysql, sql

this is what I have:

```
SELECT `id`, `names` FROM `screenplays` WHERE `names` LIKE '%joe%mike%'
```

the field names contains:

```
row1: joe
row2: mike
row3: joe,mike
```

how do I return all 3 rows as a result ?

Comment: @juergend - The example is `Joe` AND `Mike` (And in That order), where as the OP is asking for `Joe` OR `Mike`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
SELECT `id`, `names` 
FROM `screenplays` 
WHERE `names` LIKE '%joe%' 
    OR `names` LIKE '%mike%'
```

If the names are separated by a comma, and you don't want names like joey when you specify joe, you can expand on the query like:

```
SELECT `id`, `names` 
FROM `screenplays` 
WHERE `names` LIKE 'joe'
    OR `names` LIKE '%,joe'
    OR `names` LIKE 'joe,%'
    OR `names` LIKE '%,joe,%'
```

And similarly for each keyword

Comment: No, that will still match with `'me,joey,you'`.  Both the first and second OR conditions match.  The only way to ensure an exact match is to put `,` at the start of both strings...  `',me,joey,you,' LIKE '%,joe,%'`, which is what another answer here does.

Comment: @fogsy - Please note that both examples here still have the problem of in-exact matches.  `'me,frederich,you' LIKE '%rich%'` will return TRUE even though `rich` isn't in the list.

Comment: @Dems The second example wouldn't do that. Also, the other example would also select a string like `me,joey,you` if you put just me and joey as the keywords.

Comment: Sorry, but both your first and second examples ***do*** match like that.  Because you are using OR in your second example; the first condition matches `'joe'` to `'joey'`, so none of the other OR conditions matter, so it matches.  *[Michal's answer woud attempt to match `',joe,'` against `',joey,mike,'` and correctly fail the match.]*

Comment: @Dems Have you tried it?
When you search for `names` like 'joe', it will only return those with an exact match (i.e. if the column value is "Joe"). I have tested it in mysql cli with sample data and got correct results, and hence my question.

Answer (score 3):

All good answers, but I prefer to use MySQL's excellent support for regular expressions:

```
SELECT `id`, `names` FROM `screenplays` WHERE `names` REGEX 'joe|mike'
```

To take in to account comma separated names, and also white space use a more advanced regular expression:

```
SELECT `id`, `names` FROM `screenplays` WHERE `names` REGEX '(^|,) *(joe|mike) *($|,)'
```

Which breaks down to:

> ```
> (^|,)       # begin at start of line, or after a comma
>  *          # ignore any spaces
> (joe|mike)  # names to match
>  *          # ignore any spaces
> ($|,)       # ends at end of line or a comma
> ```

See [MySQL manual page for REGEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)

Comment: what about `'me,frederich,you' REGEX 'rich'`?  don't you still need the additional commas?  `',me,frederich,you,' REGEX ',rich,'`?

Comment: Good point - the beauty of regular expressions: `(^|,)(joe|mike)($|,)`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT `id`, `names` FROM `screenplays` 
WHERE concat(',', `names`, ',') LIKE '%,mike,%' or concat(',', `names`, ',') LIKE '%,joe,%'
```

Adding comma to `names` prevent returning `carlton` when you are searching `carl`.

Comment: +1 - This may seem over-complicated, but actually it's what you need.  As other wise `ike` will match with `mike`, etc, etc.